# Google Cloud SQL claims my database is much larger than MySQL-Workbench

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

On the dashbord for my gcloud SQL database it says it is using 325MB of storage, when check the total database size via MySQL-Workbench it says there is only about 1.1MB of data. It is a very small DB, all text and urls, so it definitely can't be anywhere close to 325MB.

My question is, what is causing the difference in size reporting?

Comment: Do you have lots of indexes on text columns?

Comment: Not a bunch, most tables have no indexes just pkeys and some of them are indexed on short strings (< 10 chars). The largest table contains about 300KB at most in short strings (800 rows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you deleted a lot of data from the database? InnoDB will hold onto the disk space (it will reuse the space, but never release it). That would account for the discrepancy if MySQL Workbench only takes the current amount of data that's actually in the database as its metric.

Comment: Yes, I've deleted and recreated the database probably over 100 times in the process of testing the build scripts. That makes sense. So since the real size is only around a MB, can I change the instance size to 128MB instead of 528 like I have now?

Comment: Great question. So, the answer is "yes, but it won't do what you want." What you see on https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing is that there is an amount of storage included in your tier, but changing tiers doesn't reduce the amount of maximum space you are _allowed_ (500GBs). We just then charge for whatever is over the included space.  We don't run with `innodb_file_per_table` (it's faster without on our machines) so `truncate table` won't work here. The only real solution is to create a new Cloud SQL instance and drop the old one (note that you can't reuse the old name for up to 2 months).